# How to make some part of object destructured elements const?

Tags: javascript

```
const [parentUUID, childUUID, extraUUID] = UUIDs

if (extraUUID) {
  if (extraUUID === 'questions') childUUID = childUUID + '/questions'
  if (extraUUID === 'practice') childUUID = childUUID + '/practice'
}
```

I want to make all destructured fields constant, except `childUUID`.

Comment: You'll have to use two destructuring declarations.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to do two destructure declarations as Pointy mentioned in the comments.

i.e:

```
const [parentUUID, , extraUUID] = UUIDs;
let [, childUUID] = UUIDs;
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been stated before, you need two explicit destructuring declarations then:

```
const [parentUUID,,extraUUID] = UUIDs;
let [,childUUID] = UUIDS;
```